# I'm getting Error 203 at Angular to connect at Django Rest Api

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I need  help to solve a problem. I'm developing a simple contacts system, but I`m getting some errors to list them. At Postman I can do the CRUD with the api.

In the server I get this message:

> [08/Jul/2019 18:25:35] "GET /api/contato/ HTTP/1.1" 200 230

#### This is my contato.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'; import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; import { Contato } from '../interfaces/contato'; import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class ContatoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getListaContatos(): Observable <Contato[]> {
    const url = `${environment.contatoApiUrl}/contato/`;
    return this.http.get<Contato[]>(url);   }

  getContato(id: number): Observable <Contato[]> {
    const url = `${environment.contatoApiUrl}/contato/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Contato[]>(url);   }

  addContato(contato: Contato): Observable <Contato[]> {
    const url = `${environment.contatoApiUrl}/contato/`;
    return this.http.post<Contato[]>(url, contato);   }

  atualizaContato(contato: Contato): Observable <Contato[]> {
    const url = `${environment.contatoApiUrl}/contato/${contato.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Contato[]>(url, contato);   }

  deletaContato(id: number): Observable <Contato[]> {
    const url = `${environment.contatoApiUrl}/contato/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete<Contato[]>(url);   }

}
```

#### This is my lista-contato.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'; import { Contato } from '../../interfaces/contato'; import { ContatoService } from '../../services/contato.service'; import { ErrorMsgComponent } from '../../compartilhado/error-msg/error-msg.component';

@Component({   selector: 'app-lista-contato',   templateUrl: './lista-contato.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./lista-contato.component.css'] }) export class ListaContatoComponent implements OnInit {   public contatos: Contato[];   @ViewChild(ErrorMsgComponent, {static: false}) errorMsgComponent: ErrorMsgComponent;

  constructor(private contatoService: ContatoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListaContatos();   }

  getListaContatos() {
    this.contatoService.getListaContatos()
      .subscribe((contatos: Contato[]) => {
        this.contatos = contatos;
      }, () => { this.errorMsgComponent.setError('Falha ao buscar contatos.' ); });   }

  deletaContato(id: number) {
    this.contatoService.deletaContato(id)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getListaContatos();
      }, () => { this.errorMsgComponent.setError('Falha ao deletar contatos.'); });   }

  existemContatos(): boolean {
    return this.contatos && this.contatos.length > 0;   }

}
```

**Errors from Console**

> ListaContatoComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'id' of undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListaContatoComponent.html:12)
>           at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39358)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38370)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:38664)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
>           at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38693)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38371)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
>       View_ListaContatoComponent_0 @ ListaContatoComponent.html:8

**Additional Error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contato/' from
>   origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what a [203 status code](https://httpstatuses.com/203) means? You say you're getting errors, what are those errors?

Comment: sorry for my first post.

Comment: yes I saw 203 status code means, but I don't know why.

Comment: It seems you're experiencing a few separate issues. I'd start by taking a look at what @Noremac suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cors, like @Noremac have said. An example from the [documenation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)! how you do it in Django.

Install cors with command `pip install django-cors-headers`.

Then on your settings.py file you add it in the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # I assume there are some other apps here...
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Then on in your MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE  = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # others middlewares bellow
]
```

Attention to the one above because the line with corsheaders need to be before any middleware that can generate responses, like CommonMiddleware, etc, [documentation about it here](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)!.
Then at the end of settings.py you can add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` or add the origin you want like:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '127.0.0.1:8000'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Django API must allow requests from `http://127.0.0.1:4200`. Check out [Django's documentation on CORS](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors) on how to do that. You might also be wondering, [what is CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)?

Answer (score 0):

Error at console google chrome

```
ListaContatoComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListaContatoComponent.html:12)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39358)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38370)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:38664)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38693)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38371)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38736)
View_ListaContatoComponent_0 @ ListaContatoComponent.html:8
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contato/' from
>   origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: I updated your original question with this information. Just so you know for the future you can add/edit your questions by selecting the little grey 'edit' text below the question. You should delete this info as an answer, because this is the incorrect location for such info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, worked.

But the correct syntax is:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
     "http://127.0.0.1:4200" ]
```

And the problem about "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined", was because the property was out the FOR.

Now it's ok..

Thanks